# A query with all types of constraints used in oracle SQL 10g?

Tags: oracle10g

I am unable to write a query in oracle SQL 10_g which uses all types of constraints using *employees* and *departments* tables.

Can you help me with the same?

Comment: No one can help you unless you provide more information regarding your problem.

Comment: At the very least, can you please provide some information about your db structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean:

```
select * from all_constraints
where table_name in ('EMPLOYEES', 'DEPARTMENTS');
```

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what i was looking for.